# xml based representation for java code

Tags: java, xml, jaxb2

I was looking for xml based representation for java code i found the javaML and JAXB 
I tried to find someone comparing them online, but there is not much of resources about JavaML. 
what is the difference between both and do they serve the purpose ? 
is there any advantage for using one over the other ?

Comment: JAXB is something completely different. It's a serialization thing for when you want to represent the state of an Object in XML, not the source code of the class.

Comment: thz zapl ur comment like very helpful

Comment: but does the jaxb is a serialization tech like XMLEncoder and XMLDecoder?

Comment: JAXB is similar but the resulting xml does not describe the class in any way: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Comment: does not describe the class in any way i think this property when comparing jaxb to javaml but when compare it to xmlEncoder and decoder i think both do same job is that right?

Comment: xmlEncoder includes a tiny bit of class description but it describes object state too i.e. which fields are set and what values they have. Look at e.g. [this example](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-read-a-javabean-from-an-xml-file-using-xmldecoder.html) the XML does not mention that the `MyBean` class has a `isMyBoolean` method or that the class implements `Serializable` which would be included in JavaML (and there would be no mention that the value of `myBoolean` is currently `true` because it describes the sourcecode which has no runtime state)